# Excel: Looking for a cell range by value, and returning values that aren't already specified

Tags: excel

I have dataset formatted long-wise with multiple rows belonging to one individual, each row specifying a different point in time. These rows all have the same unique ID. My first question is if there is any function that will return me the range of rows which contain a specified ID. For example:

```
   A
1 23
2 23
3 23
4 23
5 25
6 25
```

If I specified I want all rows with '23' in column A, the output would be A1:A4.

My second question would be to take that range and look up a value in a certain column in that range that hasn't already been specified in a separate range. This range of specification would be static: to the left of the current cell by 5 cells. Using the same example:

```
   A   B
1 23 peach
2 23 peach
3 23 apple
4 23 orange
5 25 cherry
6 25 cherry
```

I would specify I want to look at the values in column B. The command will see that peach is already listed in an already specified range, and leave apple as the output. Ideally this command would work again if run again to capture 'orange' in B4.

Ideally this can all be done without the use of vba. Any solution not necessarily following my logic map are appreciated as well. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Will the data always be sorted, or could you have a range with `23` that's, say, `A1:A5, A10:A11`?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: The data should always be sorted, yes. I have tried a variety of index/match functions, but I just can't seem to juggle everything in a way that would work across different ranges with different IDs.

Comment: This is really two separate questions - the second part is a bit more complicated and it would help if we could see some sample data, and sample expected output.  Perhaps break this question up, and ask that second one separately.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This should help get that first part.  Note, I am cheating a little bit and assuming you know it's in column A.  Say you put `23` in `B1`, and want to return the range that has `23`.  Enter this as an Array Formula (with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
="$A$"&MATCH(C1,$A$1:$A$6,0)&":$A$"&MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A6=C1),$A$1:$A$6),$A$1:$A$6)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I noticed I made an error in my post which I fixed: it should return the range where only 23 is listed, so A1 to A4. Also, would this work for ranges that may be larger than 6 rows? Or would I have to know that number beforehand?